# Find value in dataframe closest to a specific time ago

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a date-time column and a value column, I'd like to find a way to create another column with the value at the time closest to a given interval before the date-time.

What I'd like is to have a column called "Value 2 hours ago", and have the value of this column correspond to the "Value" column at the time that was the closest to 2 hours ago.

For example, if the "Date-Time" column shows "01/01/2014 12:10:00", this new column will return the number in "Value" in the line for which "Date-Time" is closest to "01/01/2014 10:10:00"

Even better if I can apply some conditions on this value based on how far the real time interval is from the desired "2 hours" interval. For example, "return the value closest to 2 hours ago, except if it's less than 1 hour ago or more than 3 hours ago, then return nothing"

To illustrate, here is a sample input dataframe. I can easily get the value 2 hours ago, and then self-merge it on the two date-time columns. The challenge is to have this merge be on the nearest match, rather than an exact match.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date-Time' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 04:11:00", "01/01/2014 08:10:00","01/01/2014 09:11:00","01/01/2014 12:10:00"], index=['1', '2','3', '4']),'Value' : pd.Series([9,12,3,21], index=['1', '2','3','4'])})
df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df["t_2h_ago"]=df["Time"]-pd.to_timedelta('2h')
merged=pd.merge(df,df,how='left',left_on='Time',right_on='t_2h_ago')
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code to create that column? It seems to me that at least it's quite simple with naive approach. It is better to ask a more specific question rather than just describing a requirement.

Comment: I didn't really know where to start so I was looking for a suggested approach or pseudocode. However since then I've found out about reindex with the 'nearest' method, and so I think I should be able to merge the dataframe with a copy of itself using the date-time column and a computed column that gives the time 2 hours ago. I'll try that and post it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Take the cartesian product. Then find the difference between the timestamps. Note I assumed that each date-time is unique in the function named nearest_time. Then group by and calculate the min of each group. For each group, this gives you the closest timestamp in seconds. Then join back.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date-Time' : pd.Series(["01/01/2014 04:11:00", "01/01/2014 08:10:00","01/01/2014 09:11:00","01/01/2014 12:10:00"], index=['1', '2','3', '4']),'Value' : pd.Series([9,12,3,21], index=['1', '2','3','4'])})

def nearest_time(x):
    row_i= datetime.strptime(x['Date-Time_x'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    row_j = datetime.strptime(x['Date-Time_y'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    diff = time.mktime(row_i.timetuple()) - time.mktime(row_j.timetuple()) #seconds ex(2 hrs)
    if diff == 0: diff = float('inf')
    return abs(diff)

df = df.copy()
df['key']=1
df = pd.merge(df,df,on='key')
df['diff'] = df.apply(nearest_time,axis=1)
df2 = df.copy()
df2= df2.groupby(['Date-Time_x']).agg({'diff': np.min})
df2 = df2[['diff']]
df2['Date-Time_x']=df2.index

df3 = pd.merge(df2,df, on=['diff',"Date-Time_x"])
print df3
```

Comment: Thanks but that only gives me the time 2 hours before, right? This can be done with a timedelta. My problem is more, once I have the time 2 hours before, how do I get the value associated with the time nearest to that time. I.e. if there is no "01/01/2014 02:11:00" timestamp, what is the timestamp closest to it and what is the value associated with it? I think using reindex with the 'nearest' method is one solution. I'm trying now.

Comment: I have fixed my answer to better fit the question. The general outline goes this way.
For each row find the difference between the timestamp and the time two hours ago. Store all these values in a column called diff. Then find the min value in the column diff.

Comment: Edited again now that I have a better understanding of what you are looking for.